# D3js: small square polygon renders half the map

Tags: canvas, d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to create a square polygon 10 degrees high across the whole equator line. Here's the code related to the polygon:

```
var feature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [ [-89, 0], [89, 0], [89, 10], [-89, 10], [-89, 0] ]
        ]
    },
    properties: []
}
```

But half of my map is being rendered as part of the polygon instead of just a small part of it. Posting the feature above on http://geojsonlint.com/ shows my desired result.

Here is the code and map with the issue: http://tributary.io/inlet/d86c74159991fcb9e646

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, you can see another problem on the tributary map: the polygon should be rendered above the equator line, but it's shown below it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're drawing a polygon, it'll draw a line between the two points over the shortest distance, which is a great circle.  That's why you see your polygon extend to cover half the globe.  You can avoid this by specifying some intermediate points in between the corners of your polygon.

I have done just that here: http://tributary.io/inlet/8bf24e98ac612e5e2784

The feature now looks like:

```
var feature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [ [-89, 10], [-79, 10], [-69,10], [-59, 10], [-49, 10], [-39, 10], [-29, 10], [-19, 10], [-9, 10], [0,10], 
              [9, 10], [19, 10], [29,10], [39, 10], [49, 10], [59, 10], [69, 10], [79, 10], [89, 10],  
              [89, 0], [79, 0], [69,0], [59, 0], [49, 0], [39, 0], [29, 0], [19, 0], [9, 0], [0,0], 
              [-9, 0], [-19, 0], [-29,0], [-39, 0], [-49, 0], [-59, 0], [-69, 0], [-79, 0], [-89, 0], [-89,0], [-89, 10] ] 
        ]
    },
  "properties": []
}
```

Also, don't forget to specify the points of the polygon in clockwise order, which I suspect is the issue you raised in your additional comment.  Basically, clockwise ordering is used for the outside ring of a polygon.  If you specify it in counter-clockwise, as you've done, then it'll be turned "inside out".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben. Your explanation makes perfect sense - I was here questioning my d3js fundamentals for hours yesterday and didn't know about the "shortest distance" behavior.

Again, thanks you for your answer and taking time to improve the code. I would upvote you if I could!